# testing if php string is an integer

Tags: php

`$post` is used to simulate `$_POST`, and I found that `$_POST['int']` is a string.

How can I tell whether `$post['int']` is an integer?

The following indicates that it is not an integer.

```
<?php
  $post=array('int'=>(string)123);
  var_dump($post);
  echo(is_int($post['int'])?'int':'not int');
?>
```

EDIT.  Per the documentation (http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php), `is_int — Find whether the type of a variable is integer`, so obviously it does exactly what it is suppose to do.  Still need to tell whether the string is an integer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really want to know if the value is an integer you can use [filter_input()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php). Important: you can not test this with a fake `$_POST` var, you really have to post the value or use `INPUT_GET` for testing and append `?int=344` to your URL

```
// INPUT_POST => define that the input is the $_POST var
// 'int' => the index of $_POST you want to validate i.e. $_POST['int']
// FILTER_VALIDATE_INT => is it a valid integer
filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'int', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT );
```

Working example:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="int" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
<?php
if( isset( $_POST["int"] ) ) {
    echo( filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'int', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT )  ) ? 'int' : 'not int';
}
```

**Update:**
Due to the comment of  @user1032531's answer

> I would have thought a baked-in solution would have been available

There is a built in function called [filter_var()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php), that function does the same like the above example, but it doesn't need a POST or GET, you can simply pass a value or variable to it:

```
var_dump( filter_var ( 5, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT ) );// 5
var_dump( filter_var ( 5.5, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT ) );// false
var_dump( filter_var ( "5", FILTER_VALIDATE_INT ) );// 5
var_dump( filter_var ( "5a", FILTER_VALIDATE_INT ) );// false
```

Comment: Thumbs up for filter_var - very powerful and even allows checks like valid email (FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `is_numeric` function it returns true if a `var` is `integer` or `String Integer`

```
<?php
  if(is_numeric($post)){
        //Its a number
    }
  else{
    //Not a number
 }
?>
```

If you want to know if a variable is a `integer` and not a `string integer` you can use

```
<?php
      if(is_int($post)){
            //Its a number
        }
      else{
        //Not a number
     }
?>
```

To Check if the variable is a `float` you can use `is_float();`

```
<?php
      if(is_numeric($post)){
            //Its a number
            if(is_float($post)){
               //Its a floating point number
            }
        }
      else{
        //Not a number
     }
    ?>
```

Comment: So this will tell whether it a number, but not necessarily an integer.

Comment: No a number can be an integer and string both. I you want them to be integer or string. Then when you declare a int don't put it in quotes then its a integer if you put it in quotes than it will be a string

Comment: `is_numeric('1.5')` and `is_numeric('1.0E+35')` would yield true as well – not sure if that’s what the OP wants. And as for `is_int` – values received via GET/POST are _always_ strings.

Comment: So, check if it is numeric, then type cast it as an int, then compare the two?

Comment: @cbroe i am not sure about that. @user1032531 those comparison will result same just use `is_numeric` to determine if its a `String Number` then if you wan to perform mathematical operation on it then convert it in `INT`. `var string = (int) number;`

Answer (score 3):

Don't think it is a strong solution, but...

```
<?php
function is_string_an_int($v){
    return is_numeric($v)&&(int)$v==$v;
}
echo is_string_an_int(5)?'y':'n';
echo is_string_an_int(5.5)?'y':'n';
echo is_string_an_int('5')?'y':'n';
echo is_string_an_int('5a')?'y':'n';
```

Comment: @swidmann Thanks.  I would have thought a baked-in solution would have been available.

Comment: you're welcome, and there is such a function: `filter_var()` will return the int if it's an int or false if it's not an int

Comment: @swidmann I liked your solution, but wasn't sure about having to only test on a URL, etc.  Neve rmind. Just finished reading your edited answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `is_numeric()`

From [php site documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php)

> Note:
>   To test if a variable is a number or a numeric string (such as
>   form input, which is always a string), you must use is_numeric().

I personnaly use since a while :

```
function isInteger( $nbr ) { 
      if( preg_match( "/^[-]?[0-9]+$/", $nbr ) > 0 ) { 
         return true;
      }   
      return false;
 }
```

Explanations about the regex:

```
/          begin of the regex  
^          the beginning of the string that you need to verify
[-]?       an optionnal minus sign. No more that one sign.
[0-9]+     at least one digit
$          end of the string that you want to verify
/          end of the regex
```

Comment: Per your edited solution.  I really need to get better at regex.  Not sure it works (but expect it does since you've been using it for a while), and will test.

Answer (score 0):

The following cod snippet worked for me

```
if (is_numeric($_POST['in'])) {
echo "numeric!";
} else {
echo "not numeric";
}
```