# PHP validating XML inputs as ints

Tags: php, xml

When running this code it takes an XML input and parses the key values into variables to make a simple arithmetic calculation. I attempt manually validate the user input to ensure tags number1 and number2 are integers;

When echoing the variables they appear as integers but still meet the condition as if they aren't. Please let me know if you can see any problems.

```
<?php
    $XML = “<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>.           
<arithmetic> 
<operation>add</operation>
<number1>5</number1>
<number2>3</number2>
</arithmetic>”;
    $equation = simplexml_load_string($XML); //loads xml into variable
    $operation = $equation->operation; // loads operation into variable
    $number1 = $equation->number1; // loads number1 into variable
    $number2 = $equation->number2; //loads number2 into variable

    // If the values entered are not numbers return error message
    if(is_numeric($number1) != 1){  
        $number1 = "";
        echo " Incorrect number 1 entered  ";
    }
    if(is_numeric($number2) != 1){
        $number2 = "";
        echo " Incorrect number 2 entered   ";
    }
.....
```

Comment: `is_numeric()` does not test for integers. It tests whether a variable is an integer or a [numeric string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.numeric-strings.php). You need to be more specific about what your code should accept as a number/integer.

Comment: Okay I understand, do you know if PHP supports any other functions that will check if variable is a suitable integer value ?

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to give a [mcve] - just replace the parts about `$_POST["XML"]` with a hard-coded XML string that demonstrates the problem. (The fact that it's user input isn't really relevant.)

Comment: I believe this may be more clear let me know if there’s anything that can make it easier to understand

Answer (score 1):

If you do `var_dump` on the `number1`, you will see that it is not a string, but an object of type `SimpleXMLElement`.

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)[3]
  public 0 => string '1' (length=1)
```

So simply cast the variables in order to convert them to string:

```
$operation = (string) $equation->operation; // loads operation into variable
$number1 =(string) $equation->number1; // loads number1 into variable
$number2 = (string) $equation->number2; //loads number2 into variable
```

Update: This will call `::__toString()` under the hood. check [the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php).

Comment: So when converting them to strings instead of objects of the XML it would give the expected outcome when running is numeric

Comment: @MikesCodes Yes. is_numeric is always false for objects. You need to extract it first.

Comment: @MikesCodes Please consider voting if the answer is correct and otherwise let me know to update it. :)

Comment: @MikesCodes Also see [testing if PHP string is an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33837558/testing-if-php-string-is-an-integer)

Answer (score 1):

PHP's `is_numeric()` essentially tests whether the number or string is formatted like a number, e.g. "123" or "123.45" (strings) or 123 or 123.45 (integers and floats respectively).

There's `is_int()` but that checks whether the *type* of the variable is integer. This won't help you because you're starting with a string.

Building on @pouria's answer: since you're starting with an object, you'll need to first convert it to a string with

`$number1 =(string) $equation->number1;`

That will get you a string, but to test whether it is "integer-like" (i.e. consists of only digits) you can do this:

```
// Test whether $number1 consists of at least one digit:
if ( preg_match( '/^\d+$/', $number1 ) ) {
  // $number1 is an integer!
} else {
  // $number1 is NOT an integer (or is empty)!
}
```

If you want to allow an optional leading sign (+/-) in your integers, change the regexp to:

```
'/^[+-]?\d+$/'
```

Once you've determined whether `$number` is integer-like, you may need to convert it to an actual integer (depending on how you intend to use it):

```
$number1 = (int) $number1;
```

Comment: There is a built-in function for the "digits only" case, called [ctype_digit](https://www.php.net/ctype_digit).

Comment: @IMSoP Correct, but that doesn't allow for negative integers.

Comment: Yeah, just saying it's an alternative for your _first_ regex; the second one is definitely the way to go for "any integer".

Comment: This is a great answer @kmoser . Thanks for elaborating. I would also appreciate it if you upvote my answer.